# media player in listview

Tags: android, listview, media-player

I reproduce sound in listeview . I have a custom adapter , but it always fails the line where I put the int with the resources of the mp3 ! ono sure I'm perdnto something but do not know what ! advice on how to solve? thank you

```
public class Adapter_animal extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] animal;
private final int[] animal_id;
private MediaPlayer mp;


public Adapter_animal(Activity context, int mylist, String[] animal, int[] animal_id) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, animal);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.animal = animal;

    this.animal_id = animal_id;
}

public View getView(final int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titolo);
    txtTitle.setText(animal[position]);

    FloatingActionButton btn = (FloatingActionButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.f1_btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Adapter_animal.this, animal_id);  //error in this line "cannot resolve method
            mp.start();
        }

    });











    return rowView;

};
private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

string

```
static String[] animal={
        "animale",
        "animale2",
        "animale3",

};

static int[] animal_id={
        R.raw.a11_ovation,


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array to a method that expects a single resource id...

[Documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

> `public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)`
>
> Convenience method to create a `MediaPlayer` for a given resource id. On success, `prepare()` will already have been called and must not be called again.
>
> When done with the `MediaPlayer`, you should call `release()`, to free the resources. If not released, too many `MediaPlayer` instances will result in an exception.
>
> Note that since `prepare()` is called automatically in this method, you cannot change the audio stream type (see `setAudioStreamType(int)`), audio session ID (see `setAudioSessionId(int)`) or audio attributes (see `setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes)` of the new `MediaPlayer`.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `context` - the `Context` to use
>
> `resid` - the raw resource id (`R.raw.<something>`) for the resource to use as the datasource
>
> **Returns**
>
> `MediaPlayer` - a `MediaPlayer` object, or null if creation failed

Comment: and what would I change ? sorry but I'm not an expert and I would like to figure out how to fix !

Comment: Use the indexer in your array to pass the resource id you want. ie: animal_id[0]